# how to check which settings or rules block access by firewalld

Tags: firewalld

I`m trying install a guest vm with bridge network setting on fedora 32, but in the guest can only access host when firewalld on host is turned on.

I have set `LogDenied=all`, but nothing logged.

How can I check or monitor which settings or rules in firewalld block guest vm access the network.

Comment: Have you looked at `/etc/firewalld/firewalld.conf` this is the config file for firewalld

Comment: yes, I change `LogDenied` from 'off` to `all`, but nothing was written in the log